# d3js v4 bubble chart - getting force/gravity effects back

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3 application - which features a bubble chart. I have a version which is displaying - but the old force code from version 3 - but I am unsure how to incorporate version 4 force effects. I want to give the bubbles a bit of animation - charge/gravity type effects so there is always some movement.

//old code with no force effects
http://jsfiddle.net/xzd9eamt/2/

```js
var $this = $('.bubblechart');

var data = [{
  "label": "Chinese",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "label": "American",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "label": "Indian",
  "value": 50
}];

var width = $this.data('width'),
  height = $this.data('height');

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#ff5200", "red", "green"]);

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 15,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bubblechart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bubbles = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'bubbles');



var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(12))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .nodes(data)
//.on("tick", tick);


var bubbles = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "bubbles")


data = funnelData(data, width, height);

var padding = 4;
var maxRadius = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return parseInt(d.radius)
});

var scale = (width / 6) / 100;

var nodes = bubbles.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

// Enter
nodes.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
//.call(d3.drag());

// Update
nodes
  .transition()
  .delay(300)
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius * scale;
  })

// Exit
nodes.exit()
  .transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 1)
  .remove();


draw('all');


function funnelData(data, width, height) {
  function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var max_amount = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return parseInt(d.value)
  })
  var radius_scale = d3.scalePow().exponent(0.5).domain([0, max_amount]).range([2, 85])

  $.each(data, function(index, elem) {
    elem.radius = radius_scale(elem.value) * .8;
    elem.all = 'all';
    elem.x = getRandom(0, width);
    elem.y = getRandom(0, height);
  });

  return data;
}


function draw(varname) {
  var foci = {
    "all": {
      name: "All",
      x: width / 2,
      y: height / 2
    }
  };
  //force.on("tick", tick(foci, varname, .55));
  //force.start();
}

function tick(foci, varname, k) {
  return function(e) {
    data.forEach(function(o, i) {
      var f = foci[o[varname]];
      o.y += (f.y - o.y) * k * e.alpha;
      o.x += (f.x - o.x) * k * e.alpha;
    });

    nodes
      .each(collide(.1))
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }
}


function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
  return function(d) {
    var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding,
      nx1 = d.x - r,
      nx2 = d.x + r,
      ny1 = d.y - r,
      ny2 = d.y + r;
    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
          y = d.y - quad.point.y,
          l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
          r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + padding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h1>BubbleChart I</h1>
<div class="bubblechart" data-width="300" data-height="300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to know with d3 versus d4.

Firstly, `nodes` was empty, because the new nodes were not added to the selection automatically. Since d3 v4, you need to call `.merge()` to combine the update and enter parts of a selection. [This article](https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function) is a really good summary.

Secondly, there is no need to do all this data wrangling yourself. `d3-force` updates `d.x` and `d.y` automatically with the correct values, so you can remove the `collide` function and the part where you calculate `d.x` and `d.y`. All you need to do is just draw the circles at the correct place.

```js
var $this = $('.bubblechart');

var data = [{
  "label": "Chinese",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "label": "American",
  "value": 10
}, {
  "label": "Indian",
  "value": 50
}];

var width = $this.data('width'),
  height = $this.data('height');

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["#ff5200", "red", "green"]);

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 15,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20
  },
  width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select($this[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr('class', 'bubblechart')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var bubbles = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'bubbles');

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(12))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .nodes(data);

var bubbles = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "bubbles")

data = funnelData(data, width, height);

var padding = 4;
var maxRadius = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return parseInt(d.radius)
});

var scale = (width / 6) / 100;

var nodes = bubbles.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data);

// Enter
nodes.enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .call(d3.drag());

// Update
nodes
  .transition()
  .delay(300)
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.radius * scale;
  })

// Exit
nodes.exit()
  .transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 1)
  .remove();


draw('all');


function funnelData(data, width, height) {
  function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var max_amount = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return parseInt(d.value)
  })
  var radius_scale = d3.scalePow().exponent(0.5).domain([0, max_amount]).range([2, 85])

  $.each(data, function(index, elem) {
    elem.radius = radius_scale(elem.value) * .8;
    elem.all = 'all';
    elem.x = width / 2;
    elem.y = height / 2;
  });

  return data;
}


function draw(varname) {
  var foci = {
    "all": {
      name: "All",
      x: width / 2,
      y: height / 2
    }
  };
  force.on("tick", tick(foci, varname, .55));
}

function tick(foci, varname, k) {
  return function(e) {
    bubbles.selectAll("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<h1>BubbleChart I</h1>
<div class="bubblechart" data-width="300" data-height="300" />
```

Comment: but your bubbles aren't moving etc.. -- I've always tried to put some animation into these - where the bubbles grow and float like in a pond. But this is so very static etc.. - weren't there charge properties on these?

Comment: yeah - so like your bubbles are the same size -- when the value of the bubble should reflect the size -- also - I always tried to play around with scaling the bubbles - to give some kind of retrospective scale overall to entire chart - so like draw the radius respectfully to a scale rather than a 1:1 value to radius ratio

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s50j2bqf/1/ -- yeah the circles are now different sizes - but - they draw on top - without moving etc.. - there is no repelling charge etc. -

Comment: this is your current version - http://jsfiddle.net/s50j2bqf/2/

Comment: Also noticed the drawing of the dots don't update or remove the dots - like the transitions don't work anymore on those